# Access data from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get data from an `NSDictionary` in Swift but I'm not able to do this.
Here is the code

```
    let urlPath = "http://ws-report.goocity.it/Stats/json/GetReport"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var result: NSDictionary
        if error != nil {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if err != nil {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else{
            //var arr : NSArray = jsonResult.valueForKey("Stats") as NSArray
            //var cash: String? = jsonResult.valueForKey("Cash") as? NSString
            let stats = jsonResult["Stats"]! as [[String : AnyObject]]
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

You can see the JSON clicking on the urlPath. 
I still receive the following error on the `let stats = ...`

> Thread 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

I've just checked out few other posts here on stackoverflow and anywhere, but no answer is good for my issue.

I need to get all JSON field values in many variables (like cash, lastUpdate, totalPartners, etc).

Comment: Are you 100% sure jsonResults has a value for key "Stats"? And are you sure the result would be an array containing dictionary objects?

Comment: The use of the ! is risky - it says "this value is definitely an array of dictionaries of String:Anyobject.  I would suggest you remove the ! and add a ? at the end.  You can then test the value of stats for nil and take appropriate action

Comment: For questions like this you should always include a listing of the JSON, or a representative sample thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is not an array of Dictionaries, it is just a Dictionary.

Change `[[String: AnyObject]]` to `[String: AnyObject]` and it will work.